# How to define NetworkX graph from pandas dataframe having multiple columns

Tags: pandas, cluster-analysis, networkx

I have a pandas dataframe that captures the information whether a invoice has been raised as a dispute or not based on some characteristics. I would like to run a community detection on top of this to search for patterns. But confused on how to create a graph from this. Tried like the below :

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations as comb
data = [[4321, 543, 765, 3, 2014, 54, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [2321, 657, 654, 7, 2017, 59, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['NetValueInDocCurr', 'NetWeight', 'Volume', 'BillingItems', 'FISCALYEAR', 'TaxAmtInDocCurr', 'Description_Bulk', 'Description_Car_Care', 'Description_Packed', 'Description_Services', 'Final_Dispute'])
edges = set(comb(df.columns,2))

G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

My current assumption is to define column name as node, pairwise relationship between all columns as edge and column value as edge weight. Is this the right approach? If yes, any help on the code to define weights? My idea is to start with a complete graph and use divisive methods like Girvan-Newman.

Comment: Usually for clustering with community detection you first make a knn-graph from your data and then perform the clustering on this knn-graph.